# Filtering Powershell result to avoid certain type of input pattern?

Tags: regex, powershell

With the Powershell below, I need to exclude certain user UPN (UserprincipalName) that match these patterns:

```
#EXT#
*HealthMailbox*
*svc*
*service*
```

and if possible any Username with two dots like:

```
Shared.mailbox.user
Finance.shared.mailbox
Company.Leaver.mailbox
...
```

Script:

```
Get-MsolUser -All |
Where-Object { ($_.blockcredential -eq $false) -and ($_.isLicensed -eq $true) } |
Select-Object DisplayName, UserPrincipalName | Out-GridView
```

How can I use RegEx to filter the output?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7 A similiar summary is shown, when you type `Get-Help about_regular_expressions` into your PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `-notmatch` and an appropriate regex.  I recommend [RegExStorm](http://regexstorm.net/reference) as a good reference where you can also do some [testing](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%2b%5c..%2b%5c..%2b%29%7c%28svc%29%7c%28service%29%7c%28HealthMailbox%29&i=Shared.mailbox.user%0d%0aFinance.shared.mailbox%0d%0aFinance.mailbox%0d%0aCompany.Leaver.mailbox%0d%0aService.mailbox&o=i).

Here is an example of what you final results **may** look like.  Do some testing and tweak the regex to meet you specific challenges:

```
Get-MsolUser -All |
? {  $_ -notmatch '(.+\..+\..+)|(svc)|(service)|(HealthMailbox)' } |
Where-Object { ($_.blockcredential -eq $false) -and ($_.isLicensed -eq $true) } |
Select-Object DisplayName, UserPrincipalName | Out-GridView
```

Comment: You may want to change `$_ -notmatch` to `$_.UserPrincipalName -notmatch`.

Comment: Thanks, graham & AdminOfThings, yes it works.